# NextJs Tooltip with @tippyjs/react

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tooltip, next.js, tippyjs

```
<Link href="/company/add" >
  <a title="My New Title" data-toggle='tooltip' className="btn btn-primary">My Link</a>
</Link>
```

A typical Nextjs Link about works while and adding Tippy Component looks as simple as show below but this dosent work.

```
<Tippy content="My Tooltip">
  <Link href="/company/add" >
    <a title="My New Title" data-toggle='tooltip' className="btn btn-primary">My Link</a>
  </Link>
</Tippy>
```

If anyone has done this successfully I will appreciate your help. I don't if there is about other tooltip that works easily with NextJs

Comment: In version most recent by Nextjs, not necessary to use tag <a> inside the <Link>

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<Tippy content="hi">
    <div>
       <Link href="/">
          <a>
            Home Page
          </a>
       </Link>
    </div>
</Tippy>
```

Even **MaterialUIs Tooltip** works the same way.

Comment: Don't forget to import: Tippy from '@tippyjs/react'; 
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css'; // the last is optional

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working for me.

```
<Link href="/company/add" >
<Tippy content="My Tooltip">
 <a title="My New Title" data-toggle='tooltip' className="btn btn-primary">My Link</a>
</Tippy>
</Link>
```